# Not sure what keys should be in class_weight dict to pass to Keras model.fit() method

Tags: dictionary, neural-network, nlp, parameter-passing, keras

I'm working on a text classification problem with very imbalanced classes, of which there are 94 total. I think that passing a dictionary of class weights to the `class_weight` parameter in `model.fit()` might prove fruitful for me. I've read up on how to generate good ratios; that's not a problem.

If I understand correctly, the dictionary should contain pairs of `(class: weight)`. But in my model's parlance, a sample's class (or label) is a one-hot encoded vector — not an integer (which I've seen as the keys in discussion online about the `class_weight` parameter, and which confuses me), and certainly not the label string itself. I can't have a vector as a key in a dictionary... I'd appreciate any insight.

I have tried a couple things. I did try making a dictionary of `(class: weight)` pairs in which the `class` value was merely an integer (maybe Keras ingeniously knows to associate an integer label with the one-hot vectors whose 1 is in the associated index — wishful thinking!), but performance didn't change. Then I updated the dictionary to feature an INCORRECT number of classes, and got no error messages and the same performance. So... `fit` was just neglecting it, or...?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you provide `sample_weight` at the same time? Keras `fit()` will ignore `class_weight` if you also provide `sample_weight`.

Comment: No, I didn't :(